# Firefox hangs on HTTP/2 push from my web-server Kvarn

Tags: firefox, rust, webserver, http2, rust-tokio

I'm building a [web server named Kvarn](https://github.com/Icelk/kvarn).
It has HTTP/2 support and I plan for it to be the leader in HTTP Push.

My web-server is hosting [kvarn.org](https://kvarn.org) and [icelk.dev](https://icelk.dev) if you want to test for yourself.

> The code which sends the request is [here](https://github.com/Icelk/kvarn/blob/69c92e5caf284eea67b7b4d9fbc8a8b497bc65df/src/lib.rs#L376-L426)

Recently, I ran into trouble; my push implementation does not work with Firefox.
It appears as though the streams of the resources I'm pushing are not closing;
the Firefox dev-tools shows the resources as though it hasn't received the first byte from the server yet.

> I use Rust with Tokio and the [H2](https://crates.io/crates/h2) library.

It works perfectly in Chromium-based browsers and in Safari, and I recall it working a few releases ago in Firefox.
I tested with the Tor Browser, successfully! That's weird, because Tor is built on Firefox.

I found another HTTP Pushing(?) website, [this one from the Go-lang team](https://http2.golang.org/serverpush%27). It worked in Firefox!

Next, I turned to `nghttp`.
This is the result from Kvarn:

```
[ERROR] Could not connect to the address ::1
Trying next address 127.0.0.1
[  0.013] Connected
[WARNING] Certificate verification failed: Hostname mismatch
The negotiated protocol: h2
[  0.035] send SETTINGS frame <length=12, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=2)
          [SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS(0x03):100]
          [SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE(0x04):65535]
[  0.035] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=3>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=201, exclusive=0)
[  0.035] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=5>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=101, exclusive=0)
[  0.035] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=7>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.035] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=9>
          (dep_stream_id=7, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.035] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=11>
          (dep_stream_id=3, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.035] send HEADERS frame <length=38, flags=0x25, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM | END_HEADERS | PRIORITY
          (padlen=0, dep_stream_id=11, weight=16, exclusive=0)
          ; Open new stream
          :method: GET
          :path: /
          :scheme: https
          :authority: localhost:8443
          accept: */*
          accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
          user-agent: nghttp2/1.43.0
[  0.040] recv SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=0)
[  0.040] send SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
          ; ACK
          (niv=0)
[  0.043] recv SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
          ; ACK
          (niv=0)
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) :status: 200
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) cache-control: no-store
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) server: Kvarn/0.2.0 (macOS)
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) content-encoding: gzip
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) accept-ranges: bytes
[  0.072] recv (stream_id=13) referrer-policy: no-referrer
[  0.073] recv HEADERS frame <length=79, flags=0x04, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
          ; First response header
[  0.073] recv DATA frame <length=2349, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :method: GET
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :scheme: https
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :authority: localhost:8443
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :path: /theme.css
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
[  0.073] recv PUSH_PROMISE frame <length=28, flags=0x04, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0, promised_stream_id=2)
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) :status: 200
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) cache-control: no-store
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) server: Kvarn/0.2.0 (macOS)
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) content-encoding: gzip
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) accept-ranges: bytes
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=2) referrer-policy: no-referrer
[  0.073] recv HEADERS frame <length=25, flags=0x04, stream_id=2>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
          ; First push response header
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :method: GET
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :scheme: https
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :authority: localhost:8443
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :path: /style.css
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
[  0.073] recv PUSH_PROMISE frame <length=17, flags=0x04, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0, promised_stream_id=4)
[  0.073] recv DATA frame <length=506, flags=0x01, stream_id=2>
          ; END_STREAM
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) :status: 200
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) cache-control: no-store
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) server: Kvarn/0.2.0 (macOS)
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) content-encoding: gzip
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) accept-ranges: bytes
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=4) referrer-policy: no-referrer
[  0.073] recv HEADERS frame <length=7, flags=0x04, stream_id=4>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
          ; First push response header
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :method: GET
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :scheme: https
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :authority: localhost:8443
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) :path: /script.js
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=13) accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
[  0.073] recv PUSH_PROMISE frame <length=17, flags=0x04, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0, promised_stream_id=6)
[  0.073] recv DATA frame <length=2323, flags=0x01, stream_id=4>
          ; END_STREAM
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) :status: 200
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) cache-control: no-store
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) server: Kvarn/0.2.0 (macOS)
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) content-encoding: gzip
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) accept-ranges: bytes
[  0.073] recv (stream_id=6) referrer-policy: no-referrer
[  0.073] recv HEADERS frame <length=34, flags=0x04, stream_id=6>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
          ; First push response header
[  0.073] recv DATA frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM
[  0.073] recv DATA frame <length=1717, flags=0x01, stream_id=6>
          ; END_STREAM
[  0.074] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (last_stream_id=6, error_code=NO_ERROR(0x00), opaque_data(0)=[])
```

which looks OK! It features the same data-frames as when I do the same for the Go example.

Remember I said it seemed like the streams were hanging. Well, I tried to write to each stream after I thought I closed them,
to see if they were truly closed. And they were. The HTTP/2 library I use throwed an error at me!

And lastly, I tested the `h2spec` utility. I tick all the boxes, which the Go example didn't!

I've ran out of ideas of what could go wrong.

Thanks for any help in advance, it's hugely appreciated.

Comment: Is that an advertisement or a question ?

Comment: A question. I genuinely have no clue why this is not working, and I thought it'd be good for you to know which technologies I'm using :)